# Find difference between max and min in an array in Java. I have written the code but getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, minimax

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // write your code here
 
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scn.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i] = scn.nextInt();
    }

    int max = arr[0];
    int min = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<=arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max =  arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    int diff = max - min;
    System.out.println(diff);

 }
}
```

output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 5 out of bounds for length 5    at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Comment: `i <= arr.length` should be `i < arr.length`. But your algorithm won't work if the user enters 0 for `n`; it will also result in an exception

Comment: Thanx, actually problem was int i = 0 index to i< arr.length. Now its working.